# How much memory is needed by kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am planning to have more than 500 consumers running within single application. How much heap memory will it need, as I saw spike in memory consumption with increasing number of consumers even if when there are no messages to process? Are there some estimates on consumer memory consumption?

Also, Given the message size will not be more than 1KB and we want to consume 20-30 messages in a batch, are there any configurations at consumer end that we can use to reduce the memory footprint of consumers.